# How can I tell the difference between these graphs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

How can I tell the difference between the graphs?

I typically find the VA, HA and the x and y-intercepts but in this case, they are all the same. Is it based off of testing points?

The degree seems to make a difference since $1/x$ and $1/x^3$ look the same but $1/x^2$ balloons up in the middle. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way. Think of x being rational between $(0,1)$ then for example let $x= \frac{1}{2}$ then $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}=2$ < $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2^{2}}}=4$ < $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2^{3}}}=8$. Therefore  $\frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{x^{2}}<\frac{1}{x^{3}}$ for integer x in $0< x < 1$. This is also true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. The reason $1/x^{2}$ "balloons up" is because any number squared is positive thus $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ is positive. $(-5)^2=25$ however $(-5)^1=-5$ and $(-5)^{3}=-125$ .

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$g(x)=1/x^2$ is an even function i.e. $g(-x)=g(x)$, so it is symmetric about the $y$-axis.

$h(x)=1/x^3$ would converge more rapidly to $0$ than $f(x)=1/x$ as $x \to \infty$ because $x^3$ grows more rapidly as compared to $x$ as $x$ grows larger. You may also think about the following inequality and invert it to draw the same conclusion:

$$x^3 \gt x \ \implies \dfrac{1}{x^3} \lt \dfrac{1}{x} \ \forall \ x \gt 1 \iff h(x)<f(x) \ \forall \ x \gt 1$$

Comment: so are all even powers even functions?

Comment: @user477465 Yes, but I'm unsure about the existence of any exceptions, it's better if you check the condition $f(-x)=f(x)$.